# Module parse failed: keyword 'public' is reserved

Tags: typescript, storybook, babel-loader, chromatic

I am working on storybook html and trying to publish on the chromatics. When I build the storybook in my system, it is building successfully but when I try to publish on chromatic,build fails.

it states:

```
module parse failed, keyword 'public' is reserved
file was processed with babel-loader, 
you may need additional loader to handle such files
```

The configuration being used is

```
const jsBabel = {
  test: /\.[j|t]s?$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  include: [path.resolve(config.root, config.paths.src)],
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: [
          [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
              corejs: '3.5.0',
              useBuiltIns: 'usage',
            },
          ],
          '@babel/preset-typescript',
        ],
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread'],
      },
    },
  ],
};

// select scripts loader
const scripts = [config.env === 'production' ? jsBabel : js, ts];
```

Can it be the case that my tsconfig.json has

```
    "outDir": "./dist/",
```

while for storybook build, i have folder **storybook-static**